# Why is my effect running multiple times, slowing the application after a few sends?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I have used the current code, however I am getting multiple console.logs, what am I doing wrong here?
I tried using useCallback and useMemo, but maybe I am using it wrong?

```
    useEffect(() => {
        io.on('message', data => {
            console.log(data);
            setMessages([...messages, {...data}]);
        });
    }, [messages]);

    const sendMessage = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!message) return;

        io.emit('message', {
            conversationId: conversation._id,
            message: {
                user: {
                    name: user.name,
                    _id: user._id
                },
                text: message,
                createdAt: Date.now()
            }
        });

        const data = {
            conversationId: conversation._id,
            text: message,
            fromUserId: user._id
        };
        setMessage("");
        await axios.post('/api/chat/send-message', data);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
    io.on('message', data => {
        console.log(data);
        setMessages([...messages, {...data}]);
    });
}, [messages]);
```

This effect adds an event handler to the `message` event. And it runs every time that `messages` in the dependency array changes. So I think multiple event handlers are building up every time `messages` is set.

You probably want to provide a cleanup function unbind the old handler as the return value of your effect in order to cleanup the old handlers.

Something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handler = data => {
        console.log(data);
        setMessages([...messages, {...data}]);
    };
    io.on('message', handler);

    return function cleanup() {
       // Or whatever the unbind handler syntax is for whatever io is.
       io.off('message', handler);
    };
}, [messages]);
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Don't forget to upvote and accept helpful answers. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: i cant upvote, because my reputation is not high enough

Comment: You can still accept the answer as accepted. Just click the tick icon to the left of the answer